# Как использовать python скрипт проекте на Unity 2019?

Tags: python, unity3d-android

Имеется функция на Python3.7 и Unity игра под Андроид. Функция возвращает 
 вложенный список с числами. Как можно запускать эту функцию во время игры в Unity?

Comment: В теории, можно отсылать данные на сервер, где программа на python будет обрабатывать эти данные и сохранять. А потом unity обратится к этой инфе и сохранит ее у себя

Comment: Я дополнил ответ некоторыми изменениями. надеюсь не слишком поздно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обманул автора наглым образом, мечту разрушил. 
Python можно использовать в Unity  но не основным языком а вспомогательным.

Используя `IronPython` вы сможете писать код, использовать библиотеки которые широко распространены на GitHub и вызывать код из основного кода C#.

Аналогичной функциональностью обладают библиотеки под общим названием IronRuby. Синтаксис похожий, поэтому придется потратить время лишь на подключение исходников, зато в ответ Unity станет поддерживать еще один язык.